# JOptionPane - Dialogo modal JAVA

Tags: java, modal

Quisiera que al hacer **click** en un botón "OK" (`button_OK`) se me preguntase si estoy seguro de realizar "x" acción.

Si pulso **SI** --> Código a realizar...

Si pulso **NO** --> Se cierra el `JOptionPane` y vuelvo a la ventana del mismo button_OK

**Código**:

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
Conexiones.cargar(valor, entero);
        //Cerramos el JDialog actual.
        dispose();
        //Cargamos el JDialog de compra y lo hacemos visible para interactuar con él.
        Compra c = new Compra(null, true);
        c.setVisible(true);
}
```

Quisiera algo parecido al cierre de una ventana en Java, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", 
                        "Salir de la aplicación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿Alguna idea posible?

Comment: Para lo que quieres usa mejor un Dialog con `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`. Mira la documentación Java ya que es muy fácil de usar. Si tienes problemas pon el código que has intentado para afinar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ese problema ya lo resolvi (si no estoy mal con ayuda de Google y creo que en una parte de StackOverFlow en ingles y aplica más que todo para JFrames ya que uso NetBeans), Este es el codigo, debes entender como funciona primero: 
`import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
int a = 0;
a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea salir del sistema?");
        if (a == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Realmente estas seguro?");
                if (a == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                      //Codigo de Salida
                      System.exit(0);
             }
        }`

Espero entiendas el codigo y que sea de gran ayuda :), ademas, deberias es buscar la documentación de JOptionPane, es más facil y mas util :3